# How to upload files in AWS S3 to Microsoft SharePoint？

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I want to upload files in AWS S3 bucket to Microsoft SharePoint.
But I don't have the skils about this.

I want to use AWS Lambda function to upload files.
And to get access token for SharePoint, I try to use Graph API.
These are in Python program code.
Please teach me the method.

Comment: Try providing some code and provide more context about what you have done, what error you are getting for people to help. People expect you to do your research. If you however over the down button, you will see it says "this question does not show any research effort..."

Answer (score 0):

Try using the marketplace connectors in AWS GLUE Job.